# Don't show until Observable has come back with something?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm working on adding suggestions to a search box. As you type in the input, your entry is used to build suggestions by hitting a service.

I've followed [this tutorial](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/06/taking-advantage-of-observables-in-angular2.html) and it got me something that looks like this:

```
private suggestions: Observable<Suggestion[]>;

constructor() {
    this.suggestions = this.entry.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(400)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap((entry: string) => {
        return this.api.getSuggestions(entry);
      });
}
```

What I'm hoping to do is hide the suggestions part of my UI until the observable has come back with something. The issue I'm running into is that the only thing I've gotten to work will run my api call twice. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
<div [class.hidden]="!(suggestions | async)">
  <span class="SearchDDHeader">Suggestions</span>
  <ul class="suggestion-list">
    <li *ngFor="#s of suggestions | async">
      {{ s.Category }} ({{ s.Count }})
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Using `async` means I have two things subscribed to my `suggestions` observable, which seems to be what's calling my api twice.

In plain English: "I want the div to be visible when the last array the `suggestions` Observable returned contained 1 or more items" but I'm not sure what the proper way to do that is.

Answer (score 3):

Your API is called twice because your observable is "cold". To make it hot" (i.e. shared) you need to call the `share` operator:

```
constructor() {
  this.suggestions = this.entry.valueChanges
    .debounceTime(400)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .switchMap((entry: string) => {
      return this.api.getSuggestions(entry);
    }).share();
}
```

You should be able to subscribe it twice without calling your API twice...

Answer (score 2):

You could set suggestions manually without async pipe:

```javascript
constructor() {
    this.entry.valueChanges
      .debounceTime(400)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap((entry: string) => {
        return this.api.getSuggestions(entry);
      })
      .subscribe(data => this.suggestions = data)
}
```

and HTML:

```html
<div [class.hidden]="!suggestions">
  <span class="SearchDDHeader">Suggestions</span>
  <ul class="suggestion-list">
    <li *ngFor="#s of suggestions">
      {{ s.Category }} ({{ s.Count }})
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what I've decided to do in the mean time. I don't know much about Observables so I'll leave the question open in case somebody has an idiomatic rxjs way.

Comment: What async pipe is subscribe for you, so in @dfsq answer he's doing it by himself, so basically it's the same thing.